Why spherical abbreviations will be smaller if the curved surface of lens faces the object
A real image of a distant object is formed by a plano-convex lens on its principal axis. Spherical aberration
(A) is absent
(B) is smaller if the curved surface of the lens faces the object
(C) is smaller if the plane surface of the lens faces the object
(D) is the same whichever side of the lens faces the object
The correct answer is option B . Can someone please this ?
